# Why do we conventionally label anti-particle solutions to Dirac equation with $-p$?

Tags: momentum, conventions, dirac-equation, spinors, antimatter

The spinor solutions to the dirac equation tend to be conventionally labelled as $u^s(\vec p)$ for particles and $v^s(- \vec p)$ for anti-particles.

Am I correct in thinking that these anti-particles solutions do, in fact, have momentum $+\vec p$. Howecer, since anti-particles contribute negatively to the conserved current in the Dirac field, *this* is the reason why we label the spinors with $-\vec p$? (i.e. it is more like a 'conventional current' argument than an 'anti-particles actually have opposite momentum direction to our initial solution'?

Comment: $v^s(- p) = v^s(k)$ where $k=-p$, so there is no fundamental difference between $v^s(p)$ and $v^s(-p)$. Are you asking why the mode expansion is typically written as $u^s(p) + v^s(-p)$?

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is no difference fundamentally. I'm asking why this is the convention. As in, why bother at all to have $-p$ as the convention.

Comment: The crucial point is: we label the orientation of momentum with respect to energy. The $v$ modes have negative energy, so if we write $u(p) e^{- i \omega t + i p x}$ we should write $v(p) e^{i \omega t - i p x}$. We typically relabel $p \to -p$ in the second term only so that we can pull $e^{i p x}$ out of the sum.

Comment: Ah okay I think thats my solution!